# Is there a way to get two views of the same file in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I have a super long .py file and I would like to be able to view two blocks of text from this file simultaneously. I know you can view two different files side by side, but I'd like to do this with the same file.

Thanks,
Ky

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the tab for the file you have open and choose split right or split down...
[image]